# c++ ReadProcessMemory base address + offset not working

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I'm using `DWORD BaseAddress = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle("example.exe");` to get the base address of my attached process. All of the addresses I'm using are DWORD type and I'm using 0x before the address number so it's hexadecimal and not decimal. I'm using a x64 computer. Both of these addresses I'm reading contain a text value.

This code works for a static address:

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)Address1, (LPVOID)&Address1Value, sizeof(Address1Value)*3, 0);
char PlayerNameBuffer[13] = {0};
snprintf(Address1Buffer, sizeof(Address1Value)*3, "%s", (LPVOID)&Address1Value);
ImprovedSetWindowText(Address1DisplayLabel, Address1Buffer);
```

So why doesn't this work for a dynamic address?:

```
DWORD Address2 = BaseAddress + Addres2Offset;
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)Address2, (LPVOID)&Address2Value, sizeof(Address2Value)*3, 0);
char LocationNameBuffer[13] = {0};
_snprintf(Address2Buffer, sizeof(Address2Value)*3, "%s", (LPVOID)&Address2Value);
ImprovedSetWindowText(Address2DisplayLabel, Address2Buffer);
```

Comment: How do you obtain `Address2Offset`? I don't think it matters here but technically you ought to use a 64-bit type to hold addresses if your process is a 64-bit one. DWORD is 32 bits wide.

Comment: I reverse engineered and found it. I know it's correct for 100% fact because I used another software to input the address and offset in to show what the value is, but I'm having trouble using it in c++. Also I changed DWORD to DWORD64 and it makes no difference, I don't think the problem has to do with the variable types.

Comment: My problem has been resolved, I'm using GetModuleHandle improperly.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Works With more than one offset:

```
DWORD getaddress(HANDLE handle, DWORD base, DWORD address[])
{
    DWORD addrs;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPCVOID(base), &addrs, sizeof(addrs), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(address); i++) {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, LPCVOID(addrs + address[i]), &addrs, sizeof(addrs), 0);
    }
    return addrs;
}
```

Usage:

```
DWORD base=0x0;
DWORD offsets[]={add as many as you want}
DWORD finaladdr=getaddress(handle, base, offsets);
```

Answer (score -1):

My problem has been resolved, I'm using GetModuleHandle improperly.

Comment: Please elaborate so the next person who uses it incorrectly can (1) recognize that their the wrong code matches yours and (2) see the correct code.